# How do I adjust the number of automatic completion lists in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, settings, rider

I am using JetBrains Rider 2021.3.4 version. The screen size is small because it is a laptop, and the font is large due to poor eyesight.
For me, the Automatic Completion feature Rider provides is fantastic.

But when you don't type the first few letters, there are too many suggestions.
I would like to **reduce this number from two to three**.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the autocomplete list popup by dragging the bottom and right sides.

---

**Cristik** said

This only changes the size of the UI control, it doesn't change the number of autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: This only changes the size of the UI control, it doesn't change the number of autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: @Cristik As you said, you can only resize the popup. I'll improve the answer.